# ESLint and snake_case inside TypeScript Type property

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint, typescript-eslint

I need to use snake_case for properties inside my Interfaces or Types. I set rule `camelcase` with

```
'camelcase': ["error", {properties: "never"}],
```

as it [mentioned in docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase). And it doesn't work for interfaces and types but works for JS objects.

```
export const test = {
    a_b: 1, // OK. No error
};

export interface ITest {
    a_b: number, // Identifier 'a_b' is not in camel case.eslint(camelcase)
}

export type TTest = {
    a_b: number, // Identifier 'a_b' is not in camel case.eslint(camelcase)
}
```

Error is dissapears when I set the rule to `'off'`, so this rule applies to .ts files.

So how can I use snake_case inside TS? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the rule does not work with types, I would recommend disabling this rule for TypeScript files by implementing the following blocks in your ESLint.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "camelcase": ["error"],
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
          "files": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
          "rules": {
            "camelcase": ["off"]
          }
        }
    ],
}
```

Once we've disabled that rule we can bring in `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` to apply an additional linting rule where it will lint the properties in interfaces and types correctly.

Note: You'll have to install the plugin and parser if you haven't done so, instructions can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

Ref `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention`: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md

```
{
    "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "rules": {
        "camelcase": ["error"],
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
            "error",
            { "selector": "property", "format": ["snake_case"] }
        ]
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
          "files": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
          "rules": {
            "camelcase": ["off"]
          }
        }
    ],
}
```